# the content of my webpage keeps overlapping with my background image slideshow, i've tried all i can to fix this

Tags: html, css, overlapping

You can preview the site at https://enigterry.github.io/nwtest.html . This is link to my code https://github.com/enigterry/enigterry.github.io/blob/main/nwtest.html

Comment: Welcome!, First of all, please do not link us to another webpage for showing your code, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here in the question instead, because it will be hard for us dig through the whole code to find the problem. Second, Add more details to the question and elaborate more. Good luck and have a great day

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `z-index`. You need to add z-index higher than 0 (that is being set for the hero) but to be safe say 99. Also for the z-index to work you need to set the `position` to `relative`. Also another issue is the black background added to the container which spreads across the entire page. Remove that and apply to the `.w3-content`. You will still need to work on the padding to make it look better.

```css
.w3-content {
    max-width: 980px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
 }
```

Comment: I've tried that now, doesn't seem to work still

Comment: I've tried it on your website and it seem to work fine. Can you walk me through what you have been doing and what is that you are getting? Also if you could do the minimum to share a working example here it'd be helpful to see what doesn't seem to work.

Comment: i set the z index here to 99 and make the position relative.      .cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}

Comment: Please pardon me if my writing is unprofessional am still just getting used to it all